# JavaScript indexOf() function fails in VB.Net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, date, webbrowser-control, indexof

This code works well in most *(all?)* browsers:

```
    myDate = new Date();
    alert(myDate.toString().indexOf("("));
```

However, when executed within a VB.Net WebBrowser control, it returns **-1**.

Why is that?

Comment: What's the point of the code??

Comment: _"It returns -1"_ because `"("` is not found in the result of `myDate.toString()`

Comment: It's meant to strip the timezone out, which is displayed within brackets ().

Comment: @iSofia: On the implementations you've seen before, perhaps, but that's not in any way required of it. The format is almost completely unspecified.

Comment: In my real time tests, _myDate_ returns the following string: `Mon Aug 10 2015 14:21:55 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`

Comment: How could I strip out the `(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`portion from the displayed date.

Comment: @iSofia: If the string had `(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)` in it, `indexOf('(')` wouldn't return -1. So clearly it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your help. It turns out that VB.Net's web browser displays the date without the time zone, _and thus no brakcets, and accordingly indexOf() returns -1_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is that?

`Date`'s `toString` is not required to output a string that has any `(` in it. If the string doesn't have a `(` in it, `indexOf` will return -1.

From [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring):

> 1. Let O be this Date object.
> 2. If O does not have a [[DateValue]] internal slot, then
>
>    - Let tv be NaN.
> 3. Else,
>
>    - Let tv be this time value.
> 4. Return ToDateString(tv).

...where [`ToDateString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-todatestring) says:

> 1. Assert: Type(tv) is Number.
> 2. If tv is NaN, return "Invalid Date".
> 3. Return an **implementation-dependent String value** that represents tv as a date and time in the current time zone using a convenient, human-readable form.

So that could use no timezone indicator, or a Z to indicate GMT, or a timezone indicator that doesn't use `(...)` like `GMT+04:00` or `-05:00` or similar, etc.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be able to display the date string without using the _toString()_ function. But the date is displayed with the time zone: `Mon Aug 10 2015 14:21:55 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`. Without using the _toString()_ function, I'm not able to use the _indexOf()_ function, to determine the location of the first bracket.

Comment: @iSofia: I don't know what you mean by "display" in that sentence. `alert(new Date())` will use `toString`. If `toString` were returning a string with parentheses in it, `indexOf('(')` wouldn't return -1. So clearly it isn't. You're going to have to modify your code so it doesn't assume a `(`, since the specification is clear that none is required.

Comment: Thank you, T.J. Crowder. In all haste I didn't bother with due diligence. For some reason, browsers tend to display the date with the timezone, but VB.Net's web browser control does not - _thus the -1 result_.  So strange.